# jQuery Plugin - Calling a function return Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am not sure how to call the function in jQuery Plugin. 
I am trying to make something small like social sharer, it would be my first plugin but I am confused.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '_echoCookie'
```

Here's what it does...

```
function EchoSoc(element, options) {
    this.element = element;

    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
}
```

After that we have some stuff into `init: function () { }` such as:

```
$('body').append( //-->
                '<div id="fb-root" />'
            +   '<script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk"));</script>'
            +   '<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>'
            +   '<script src="//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>'
            // <--
            );
```

and as this is a test for google as sample here's one last piece:

```
$('.echoGoogle').append('<g:plusone size="medium" href="' + this.options.google_url + '" callback="googleCB"></g:plusone>');
```

Then we have these functions:

```
_echoEvents: function () {
        googleCB = function() {
            this._echoCookie();
        };
    },
    _echoCookie: function () {
        $.cookie('echoSoc', 'done', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
        console.log('cookie added');
    }
```

But this simply won't work...

```
_echoEvents: function () {
        googleCB = function() {
            this._echoCookie();
        };
    }
```

**Well my question is how to call the function within other functions below init... this._functionName(); only works into init not in the functions below it.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Can you share how `_echoCookie` and `_echoEvents` are called

Comment: echoCookie is suppoused to be called within events. and _echoEvents is called within init: function()

Comment: @NenaddvL May I suggest you to have a look at http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-best-practices/? I see that you rely on some global variables and that's an extremely bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as given below since, when you call `_echoCookie` with in `_echoEvents` the `this` variable might be pointing to a different context. So use a closure variable to hold the reference to the main object and use it inside `googleCB`

```
_echoEvents: function () {
    var that = this;
    googleCB = function() {
        that._echoCookie();
    };
},
_echoCookie: function () {
    $.cookie('echoSoc', 'done', { expires: 30, path: '/' });
    console.log('cookie added');
}
```

Comment: Now I am really confused. This actually works. Thanks for explanation... Checking as correct answer as soon as possible.